# How to generate Domain Service Class for Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, nhibernate, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight application that is making calls via WCF RIA Services.  I have service proof of concept examples that reference both the Entity Framework and Linq to SQL, but am now on a project that requires NHibernate instead of EF or L2S.

How would I add a Domain Service Class that uses already generated NHibernate classes instead of one of the other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [working example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NHibernate-Sample-16eaf868) of a Domain Service using NHibernate and a quick [walk-through](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/dinesh/archive/2010/10/02/getting-started-with-wcf-ria-services.aspx) for creating a basic empty domain service from scratch.

Also, any objects in your service you are returning must have a Key attribute on a property or else the Web.g.cs (generated code) file on the Silverlight side won't get generated and you won't be able to call, won't see in Data Source window etc.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate doesn't really enforce some special class convention. NHibernate is able to work with POCO. What is more, if you have good design changing between EF + Linq2SQL and NHibernate should be invisible for clients of your service.

Comment: I have updated my question to be a bit more clear.  I am not using EF or L2S.  I just meant to state I have working examples I can test against, but really need to move to NHibernate

Comment: Ok, what is your question then? You may move to NHibernate IMHO.

Comment: All the examples I can find of setting up a domain service class involve pointing it to a L2S or EF model, then having it auto generate the service calls for you.  Since I am new to WCF I am not sure how to manually or automatically create a domain service that uses NHibernate instead of EF or L2S.

Comment: If I look at example like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556025(v=vs.91).aspx it says to choose Product and Category for code generation. These classes will look almost identically with NHibernate (you will need to mark fields as virtual - but that's all).

Comment: However, it also says: _The NWDomainService class exposes the entities on the ProductDbContext class, which, in turn, derives from the DbContext base class_, so you will have to try it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to help you more with this issue. If code generation depends on EF context then it be might impossible to do this with NHibernate. You may try to recreate given example with NH and check if it works.